# ElasticGraph - not able to find one particular index

Tags: elasticsearch, graph

I am running this following query on Elastic search Index.

```
GET researchdocs3/_graph/explore{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "_all",
        "query": "basic_materials"
    }
},
"controls": {
    "use_significance": true,
    "sample_size": 2000,
    "timeout": 5000
},
"connections": {
    "vertices": [
        {
            "field": "terms",
            "size": 2,
            "min_doc_count": 3
        }
    ]
},
"vertices": [
    {
        "field": "terms",
        "size": 2,
        "min_doc_count": 3
    }
]}
```

the query term "basic_materials" is there in indexes enough number of times, but when i run above mention query , it returns zero results.

I want to know, why exactly its not able to find "basic_materials" but its able to find other terms easily from same index.